# White Lotus Riposte and AOE at-will attacks

Tags: dnd-4e

If i for example hit 3 enemies with Cloud of Daggers on my turn ( and i have White Lotus Riposte feat ), and on their turn all 3 of them attack me, will each of them take damage from at-will ability modifier damage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

White Lotus Riposte's recourse damage does not have an action type, so you are not limited to 1/round, and it is not an attack, so you are not limited to 1/turn, if your DM rules that actions whose types are unlisted are Free Actions rather than No Actions.

That said, it's pretty difficult to target/hit 3 targets with cloud of daggers, which targets only one square.